# Memory allocation of pointer working for fixed variable assigned string but not for user input string

Tags: c, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets, c-strings

Given program is working for string that is fixed in code for example

```
char str[100] = "With fixed string this code works"
// Output of the program is "fixed string this code works"
```

But as soon as I take the `str` input using

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

it seems error is found with memory allocation because after input is given code returns error value.

The full code is as following

```
int main (void) {
    char str[100];
    char *p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * str[100]);
    printf("Enter something: ");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    *p = str;
    p = strchr(str, ' ');
    puts(p + 1);

    // Check for the first space in given input string if found then 
    while (*p++)
        if (*p == ' ' && *++p)
            printf("%s", *p);

    printf ("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if for dynamic memory allocation while using `scanf` function to input string any other allocation process is required

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings and **read them**.  You should be getting quite a few.

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to take a string from the user and then print out all characters after the first space?

Comment: @CodeWash yes, exactly that I am trying to do

Comment: @user7254101 After this assignment  p = strchr(str, ' '); p is equal to NULL.

Comment: what *value* do you think you are passing to `malloc()`?  take careful note of the answer from Craig Estey : you are passing in the *value found at* `str[100]`, which I'm guessing is not what you intend to be doing

Comment: @user7254101 Forn starters explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Shouldn't `p` be equal to the address of first space? -http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

Comment: @NAND It is unclear whether fe wants to output each word or the whole string after a space.

Comment: Hey @user7254101 , Can you add more details on your post and sample input and output and consider give feedback on the answers, commenting to know specific detail, upvote or downvote ?

Comment: @NAND I want rest of the string after the first white space detected. And as of I could understand is that scanf is not the suitable function to take input with white spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have four problems:**

---

**First**: with `scanf`, it should be like that:

```
scanf("%s",str);
```

because `str` is an address. Also make sure that `scanf` will scan for a string from `stdin` until it finds space or new line and that what you don't want. So you'd better use `fgets(str, 100, stdin);`.

---

**Second**: with `malloc`, it should be like that:

```
malloc(sizeof(char)*100)
```

because `str[100]` has not a specific value.

---

**Third**: You shouldn't change the address of memory allocated using `malloc`

`malloc` function allocates memory in heap and return the address of memory allocated, so you shouldn't do this `p = strchr(str, ' ');` since [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) will return the address of the first occurrence of the space (the address returned by `malloc` will be lost) .

---

**Fourth**: freeing the memory allocated using `malloc`

You should free the memory allocated using `malloc` using `free` function which take the address of the memory allocated.

Your code should be like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void) {
    char str[100];
    char *p = malloc(sizeof(char)*100); //Do NOT cast the return of malloc
    printf("Enter something: ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin); //Use fgets to include the spaces between words 
    strcpy(p, str);//use stcpy to Not change the address of memory allocated

    //p = strchr(str, ' '); -->This step will change the address
    //of memory allocated using malloc
    //puts (p + 1);
    /*Instead you can do this*/
    char *c = strchr(str, ' ');
    puts(c+1);

    // Check for the first space in given input string if found then 
    char *mem =p;
    while (*p++)
      if (*p == ' ' && *++p)
        printf ("%s", p);

    printf ("\n\n");
    free(mem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is now printing several remainders for every detected white spaces. But my intention was to print just the remainder of the string only once after the first white space is found

Comment: I think what you want can be achieved after removing `while` loop , isn't it? :)

Comment: replacing `while (*p++)` with `if(*p++)` made it functioning what i was wanting it to. Thanks dude:)

Comment: @user7254101 Not at all ;). Also consider freeing memory allocated using `malloc` by using `free` function. I updated the answer :D.

Answer (score 3):

Your `malloc` has a bug:

```
char *p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*str[100]);
```

Let's simplify a bit first.

---

Don't cast `malloc` (See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)):

```
char *p = malloc(sizeof(char)*str[100]);
```

---

`sizeof(char)` is (by definition) *always* 1 on *all* architectures, regardless of how many bits it occupies, so we can eliminate it:

```
char *p = malloc(str[100]);
```

---

Now we have:

```
char str[100];
char *p = malloc(str[100]);
```

You have *undefined behavior*. `str` has no values (i.e. unitialized) and you are passing the element that is one *past* the end of the array, so you have undefined behavior.

So, the length parameter passed to `malloc` is, thus, random.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf %s only reads in a string up to the first whitespace and then stops, which is probably what is causing you problems. I would avoid scanf anyway, it's dangerous and can cause problems if you're not familiar with it. You could try fgets to read from stdin instead. See if this does what you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main (void) 
{
    char *str = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH + 1);
    bzero(str, MAX_LENGTH + 1);

    printf("Enter something: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

    // Remove the newline
    if ((strlen(str) > 0) && (str[strlen (str) - 1] == '\n'))
    {
        str[strlen (str) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    char *p = strchr(str, ' ');

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        // Pointing to the space, which we will skip
        p++;
        printf ("%s\n\n", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for memory allocation, no need to clear this memory, `bzero` is BSD specific and obsolete, test if `fgets()` returned `NULL`, use `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` to strip the newline if any.